# HP QC 12 and MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access, vba, hp-quality-center

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to connect to HP QC 12 via MS Access and import the data found in table bug via a simple query. However, I'm having a hard time getting the HP QC data into a usable query.

I've tried two ways so far:

```
Public Function import_HPQC()
Dim QCConnection
Dim Com
Dim HPQC_RST As TDAPIOLELib.Recordset

Set QCConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")

QCConnection.InitConnectionEx <>
QCConnection.login <>, <>)
QCConnection.Connect <>, <>
QCConnection.IgnoreHTMLFormat = True

Com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM bug"
Com.Execute

Set HPQC_RST = Com.Execute

rcount = 0

HPQC_RST.First
    Do Until HPQC_RST.EOR
        rcount = rcount + 1
        HPQC_RST.Next
    Loop

MsgBox (rcount)

QCConnection.Logout

End Function
```

This first way works in the way that I'm able to at least get an accurate record count of what is contained in bug but I can't get past this part. I can't figure out a way to simply run an insert into against HPQC_RST.

The other way I've tried is basically the same, but instead of a select query I'm attempting to define BugFactory.NewList("") as a recordset but that just isn't working either. I'm able to loop through a BugList in the following fashion but I think it's a really messy solution and I would much rather simply append everything from bug directly into an MS Access table.

```
Set BugFactory = QCConnection.BugFactory
Set BugList = BugFactory.NewList(“”)

    For Each Bug In BugList
        HPQC_Table.AddNew
        HPQC_Table![ID] = Bug.Field("BG_BUG_ID")
        HPQC_Table.Update
    Next
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been working on this for a few days and have made very little progress.

Comment: I managed to dig up a reference guide for the OTA API and figured out how to loop through HPQC_RST. Still can't figure out how to simply use a select query to view what is inside HPQC_RST.

Answer (score 1):

You're connecting to the API, not to the actual database. If the API only provides recordset-like objects that you can loop over, that's probably what you will have to do.

(/me smiling a little at the remnants of TestDirector in the object names)